# i get same accessToken on refreshToken endpoint in JWT

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

```
  const refreshToken = req.body.token;
  console.log(refreshToken);
  if (refreshToken == null) return res.status(401).send("Not authorized");
  if (!refreshTokens.includes(refreshToken))
    return res.status(403).send("token is valid");
  jwt.verify(
    refreshToken,
    "my refresh secret",
    (err, user: Prisma.User) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      const accessToken = jwt.sign(
    user,
    "my access secret",
    { expiresIn: "15s" }
  );
      res.json({ accessToken: accessToken });
    }
    
  );
};
```

that endpoint creating me the same accessToken that i created on endpoint login should other

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: normally i should got new accessToken that is deferent than previous cuz i got jwt is expired thats my goal

Comment: I don't know where you are looking try with the debugger tool to see if the value of the access token is really the same that would really surprise me

Comment: Don't look at the response at the first time

Comment: backend gives me the same accessToken which is expired after 15s in response then my middleware gives me error jwt is expired.I saw that in my server console logs that is the same

Comment: Wait something is not clear for me.

Comment: You work on the front of the project as I understand. Why would you like to sign in with your private key?

Comment: i am creating fullstack project i wrote to you on ig can you response me? i will send you entire repo to review

Comment: Add me on LinkedIn Ethan Sayagh. I'm trying to not use Ig.

Comment: I added you.Wiktor bro.